# In a multiplayer game, why doesn't the server treat the client like a media player?

Tags: c#, xna, directx

As you already know, when you open up Youtube, there is an option for 1080p videos.
My question is, why doesn't the server treat a client as a media player?

So basically, the client sends ONLY input to the server, as in what buttons are pressed, and the server does the drawing, and sends it back to the client as a video, as Youtube would.
Maybe it might be hard for the server to do all the drawing for several players in a game, but this will prevent cheating *almost* 100%. (Color-related hacks won't stop..)

*Should I put this on gamedev?*

But won't this be a good idea if the server is a super computer, and there aren't many players?

Comment: latency latency latency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Servers tend to focus on the game logic rather than any rendering, they are responsible for keeping control and synchronising clients to allow clients to perform more complex calculations as part of the rendering process if we change that we face an entirely different problem ...

A video stream is simply a series of images, a fully featured game by todays standards is built up of a full 3D environment in which complex interactions and physics take place.

That of course raises the question ... how does the server render all those viewpoints at once in order to produce the video stream does it need 1 GPU per player like your home pc?

You also have to consider that the internet is unreliable when it comes to bandwidth. The average users home broadband connection gets fits and spurts of bandwidth which is why video streaming is always seemingly smooth and gaming laggy.

Think about it this way ...
In a game I hit the forward key and all other players around me need to know this instantly.
So I need on demand bandwidth as soon i do something or as soon as somehting around me happens.

In a normal video stream, As long as the server can get the first 30 seconds to me in a hurry the rest can come down as bandwidth allows. 
So I might be able to get a quick burst of data for 30 seconds worth of video but then for the next say 25 seconds I need no data at all from the server because I have enough to keep the video player going, something that would rarely happen in a game.

For example ...
How often does someone do something unexpected in call of duty?

Comment: Hmm, makes sense. Since videos buffer the next say 30 seconds, that's why it doesn't lag. But in a game, you can't buffer the future, so it would lag. Maybe this might become possible in the future though.

Comment: The way how I see it, you can never buffer a system that requires a realtime response, the only solution is a realtime data stream. It's a nice idea though. The big guys get round it by adding a "weight" to network operations and by updating less frequently un essential goings on. for example a grenade that goes off slightly off screen does not always need to have a precise position from the server, just a rough idea, so the client may be able to "guess" when not given specifics from the server.

Answer (score 2):

This is what companies like OnLive are offering already. http://www.onlive.com/

You just have a problem with the latency. When you are playing a shooter you want to have the lowest latency as possible. Gamers optimize this with a faster mouse, faster screen with less ghosting etc.
When your game is like a video, the latency (ping) will become very large. Only difference is that everyone is lagging.

Comment: Hmm never knew that. Yea, should have thought about the lag. Since Youtube usually doesn't lag on lower resolutions, I thought it shouldn't a problem. But, this type of gaming wouldn't really be a good idea right? It's still kinda new, probably very laggy like OnLive?

Comment: Ps. Has anyone used OnLive? Is it worth it? Does it lag a lot?

Comment: "Since Youtube usually doesn't lag on lower resolutions" different thing! If your video is constantly running 0.5s behind, you won't notice. However, if your input is visible only after one round trip of about 1 sek., that is *very* annoying.

Comment: "Since Youtube usually doesn't lag on lower resolutions, I thought it shouldn't a problem"...that's not necessarily true. For all you know, you have a high latency connection to youtube. But since you're streaming a non-interactive video, you wouldn't be able to tell, because everything is lagging at more or less the same rate, and the player buffers the stream before displaying it. In a game, you would have neither luxury. You'd have several clients lagging at different rates, and you can't buffer the stream without increasing the perceived lag (and interpreting the input timings too).